# Difference between Fuzzy and Match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I wanna know the difference between the kind of search  in Elasticsearch: Fuzzy and Match

I mean the advantages and disadvantages of each one, If anyone is better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzy can help you search ***within*** a term, match will match a ***whole*** term.

Take this example:

```
POST index1/test1
{
  "field1": "this is a full on sentence"
}
```

Fuzzy will match part of a term (each word is a term)

```
GET index1/test1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "field1": "ull"
    }
  }
}
```

Term match will not find the record because "ull" is not a full term.

```
GET index1/test1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": "ull"
    }
  }
}
```